# Received Id instead of enum text value from dropdown in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, jsp, enums

I have an **Enum**

```
package com.javarnd.bbms.enums;

public enum BloodTypeEnum {
    A_PLUS(1, "A+"), B_PLUS(2, "B+"), O_PLUS(3, "O+"), AB_PLUS(4, "AB+"), A_MINUS(5, "A-"), B_MINUS(6, "B-"),
    O_MINUS(7, "O-"), AB_MINUS(8, "AB-");

    private final int value;
    private final String name;

    private BloodTypeEnum(int value, String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public static BloodTypeEnum getEnumByName(String name) {
        BloodTypeEnum[] modes = BloodTypeEnum.values();
        if (modes == null) {
            return null;
        }
        for (BloodTypeEnum mode : modes) {
            if (mode.getName().equals(name)) {
                return mode;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static BloodTypeEnum getEnumByValue(int value) {
        BloodTypeEnum[] modes = BloodTypeEnum.values();
        if (modes == null) {
            return null;
        }
        for (BloodTypeEnum mode : modes) {
            if (mode.getValue()==value) {
                return mode;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

In My **Controller**

```
@GetMapping("/add_donor_details")
    public ModelAndView addDonorDetails(HttpServletRequest request) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("admin/add_donor_details");
        DonorDetail donorDetail = new DonorDetail();
        mav.addObject("command", donorDetail);
        mav.addObject("pageTitle", "Add Donor Details");
        mav.addObject("submitBtn", "Add Donor");
        mav.addObject("bloodGroup", BloodTypeEnum.values());
        mav.addObject("action", "./save");
        return mav;
    }

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public ModelAndView saveDonorDetails(@ModelAttribute("command") DonorDetail donorDetail, HttpServletRequest request,
            final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("");
        DonorDetail dDetail = new DonorDetail();
        try {
            String bloodType = BloodTypeEnum.getEnumByValue(Integer.parseInt(donorDetail.getBloodGroup())).getName();
            dDetail.setBloodGroup(bloodType);
            dDetail.setDonorName(donorDetail.getDonorName());
            dDetail.setGuardianName(donorDetail.getGuardianName());
            dDetail.setAge(donorDetail.getAge());
            dDetail.setEmail(donorDetail.getEmail());
            dDetail.setContact(donorDetail.getContact());
            donorDetailService.save(dDetail);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("successMsg", "Donor Details Saved Successfully");
            mav.setViewName("redirect:./add_donor_details");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("errorMsg", "Failed to add Donor details,Try Again!!");
            mav.setViewName("redirect:./add_donor_details");
        }
```

see the line

```
        String bloodType = BloodTypeEnum.getEnumByValue(Integer.parseInt(donorDetail.getBloodGroup())).getName();
```

I need to perform this additional step because, instead of getting text value I am getting the Enum Id like 1,2,3,4..

the drop down is properly renders in jsp, but when the value passed form the JSP to controller, is in the form of Id not in textual value, What I did wrong?

**JSP** Snippet

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label class="control-label"><strong>Blood Group</strong><span style="color: #FF0000; font-size: 20px;">*</span></label>
                                <f:select path="bloodGroup" id="bloodGroup" class="form-control"
                                    data-validate="required" style=" width: 100%">
                                    <f:option value="">Select Blood Group</f:option>
                                    <c:forEach items="${bloodGroup}" var="bg">
                                        <f:option value="${bg.value}">${bg.name}</f:option>
                                    </c:forEach>
                                </f:select>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the DonorDetail class set the type of bloodType to int and

```
String bloodType = BloodTypeEnum.getEnumByValue(donorDetail.getBloodGroup()).getName();
```

Comment: I agree, bu the problem , I dont need to perform this additional step in my previous project, it automatically pass the text based value, also if i remove this line then i will get the Id saved in my database,

Comment: Isn't seem the by default nature of enum?, when it is passed through jsp to controller.